# What does it mean by "a hotspot for anti-microbial resistance"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

"Widespread dumping of antibiotics in rivers has made the country a hotspot for anti-microbial resistance. "
What does it mean by "a hotspot for anti-microbial resistance"?

Comment: Please provide a citation and link to the quote. We are a bit fussy about that here. They mean the microbes there have developed resistance to anti-microbial agents (antibiotics) to an extreme degree due to low level exposure to them. It's a bit clunky because *hotspot* usually refers to something a bit more concrete or visible than *anti-microbial resistance*. Presumably, the surrounding text supplies some context of a threat to humans.

Answer (score 1):

> **hotspot** *noun*
>   2 A place of significant activity, danger, or violence.
>   ‘they identified eight pollution hotspots at the mouth of the Thames’
>   ‘teams will patrol anti-social behaviour hotspots in all parts of the borough’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hotspot)

The author asserts that the dumping of antibiotics has led to a *large and dangerous rise* in anti-microbial resistance.